# Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/DroolsPackage/LATEST

Tags: web-services, drools, guvnor

Enlisted is the way I use to read the rules from the Guvnor , for validating an input given by the user
1. A web-app(Tomcat v7.0 server) that forms the GUI for the user
2. A web-service (JBoss EAP 6.0) that reads the rule from the Guvnor using drools APIs and exposes them as a web serivce
3. Guvnor(Jboss AS 7) that acts as the repository of the rules .

When I try to submit the form (web app) , I get the following error on my console :-

```
INFO  [stdout] (Thread-77) [2012:10:296 10:10:504:info] KnowledegAgent has started listening for ChangeSet notifications
10:52:17,800 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) (null: 5, 174): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'change-set'.
10:52:17,831 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2012:10:296 10:10:831:info] KnowledgAgent applying ChangeSet
10:52:17,831 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2012:10:296 10:10:831:debug] KnowledgeAgent subscribing to resource=[UrlResource path='http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/DroolsPackage/LATEST']
10:52:17,831 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2012:10:296 10:10:831:debug] ResourceChangeNotification subscribing listener=org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl@295b9a to resource=[UrlResource path='http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/DroolsPackage/LATEST']
10:52:17,831 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2012:10:296 10:10:831:debug] ResourceChangeScanner subcribing notifier=org.drools.io.impl.ResourceChangeNotifierImpl@13d0493 to resource=[UrlResource path='http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/DroolsPackage/LATEST']
10:52:17,831 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2012:10:296 10:10:831:debug] KnowledgeAgent ChangeSet requires KnowledgeBuilder
10:52:17,831 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2012:10:296 10:10:831:debug] KnowledgeAgent rebuilding KnowledgeBase using ChangeSet
10:52:17,831 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2012:10:296 10:10:831:debug] KnowledgeAgent building resource=[UrlResource path='http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/DroolsPackage/LATEST']
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2012:10:296 10:10:955:exception]
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) java.lang.RuntimeException: KnowledgeAgent exception while trying to deserialize KnowledgeDefinitionsPackage  
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.rebuildResources(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:418)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.applyChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:120)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.applyChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:109)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at com.test.drools.ExposeDroolsWebService.checkedColor(ExposeDroolsWebService.java:50)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:194)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
10:52:17,955 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/jboss-brms/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/DroolsPackage/LATEST 
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.drools.io.impl.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:76)
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.rebuildResources(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:407)
10:52:17,971 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1)   ... 29 more
```

Here is the code that I use for accessing the rules :-

```
Resource resource = ResourceFactory
            .newClassPathResource("com/test/rules/Color.xml");
    KnowledgeAgent kagent = KnowledgeAgentFactory
            .newKnowledgeAgent("kagent");
    kagent.monitorResourceChangeEvents(true);
    kagent.applyChangeSet(resource);
    KnowledgeBase kbase = kagent.getKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.getKnowledgePackages();
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    ksession.insert(colorBean);
    ksession.fireAllRules();
    System.out.println(colorBean.getColor());
    ksession.dispose();
    return colorBean;
```

Can somebody help me in resolving this error .

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Error 401 means you are not authorized to access that URL. You need to provide username / password to guvnor.

The following code reads the DRL into a String variable from guvnor.

```
private static final String AUTH = "guvnor:guvnor";
private static String readRulesFromGuvnor(URL url, String authString) {
    String returnStr = "";
    try {
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        if (authString != null) {
            byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
            String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        }
        returnStr = IOUtils.toString(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        LOGGER.info("Rules read from: {}", url.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
        return returnStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using with Guvnor then it expects a basic authentication for the package snapshot, add the username and password by default empty to package url in your change-set xml

`<resource source="http://127.0.0.1:8888/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/mortgages/LATEST"
    type="PKG" basicAuthentication="enabled" username="admin" password="admin" />`